# Match upto x regex or y regex

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I currently have this:

```
^(.+)\(\w+\)|^(.+)\s\(\d{3}\:\d{3}\s\-\s\d{3}\:\d{3}\)
```

The #1 it only matches **Foo's**
#2 **Foo has** which is correct
#3 does match **foo** but it's in the 3rd array item [2]:

```
3rd array output:
    (
        [0] => Foo (100:200 - 300:400)
        [1] => 
        [2] => Foo
    )
```

The bold is what I'm trying to match:
**Foo's (match11) this** (100:200 - 300:400) the end **#1**
**Foo has** (not_matched) (100:200 - 300:400) the end **#2**
**Foo** (100:200 - 300:400) the end **#3**
*note: im not trying to match the #1,#2,#3 at the end of each line, thats just for reference.*

If "(100:200 - 300:400)" is found then get any text in front of it, elseif "(not_matched) (100:200 - 300:400)" found then get any text in front of it, else get text in front of "(100:200 - 300:400)"

The elseif part "(not_matched) (100:200 - 300:400)" can be identified as it only has 1 white space between the 2 round brackets of not_matched and (100:200 - 300:400)



**Edit:**

This is what i'v come up with which does seem to work, though it requires some workarounds in php to be useful.

```
(.+)\s\(\w+\)\s\(|(.+)\s\(\d{3}\:\d{3}\s\-\s\d{3}\:\d{3}\)
```

Working example: http://www.rubular.com/r/NSpGcnyg0p
For some reason it doesn't seem to save my example, so you will have to copy/paste it in.

But the regex doesn't have a direct match on each of them, thats why I have to remove the empty array element in php so that I get the result in the [1] element.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong in my regex?

Comment: Please, make your question more clear...

Comment: Yeah sorry about that, got a bit confused as to what I was trying to do, think I'v cleared it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
^.*?(?=\s*(?:\(not_matched\)\s)?\(\d+:\d+\s*-\s*\d+:\d+\))
```

or, in PHP:

```
if (preg_match(
    '/^                   # Anchor the match at start of line
    .*?                   # Match any number of characters lazily
    (?=                   # until just before the following:
     \s*                  # - optional whitespace
     (?:                  # - the following group:
      \(not_matched\)\s   #    - literal (not_matched), followed by 1 whitespace
     )?                   #   (which is optional)
     \(\d+:\d+\s*-\s*\d+:\d+\) # a group like (nnn:mmm - ooo:ppp)
    )                     # End of lookahead assertion
    /x', 
    $subject, $regs)) {
    $result = $regs[0];
} else {
    $result = "";
}
```

Comment: I knew it was possible in one regex, just had to get my question right. thanks

Answer (score 0):

This will match your second example: `(.+)(\([\D]+\).+)(\#\d+)`.

And this one will match two others: `(.+)(\([\d\W]+\).+)(\#\d+)`.

Comment: Close, but for #2 it matches "(not_matched)" which I don't want. I only want it to match "Foo has" for #2

Answer (score 0):

If I clearly understand, this should do the trick:

```
/^(.+)(?:\(not_matched\)\s)?(?:\(\d+:\d+\s-\s\d+:\d+\))\s.+\s(#\d+)$/i
```

Comment: The 2nd one im trying to only match"Foo has" but this regex also matches the "(not_matched)" part which I don't want to match.  Array
        (
            [0] => Foo has (not_matched) (100:200 - 300:400) the end #2
            [1] => Foo has (not_matched) 
            [2] => #2
        )

Answer (score 0):

This does seem to work, but needs a little workaround to be useful in php. (read my original question).

I'll select this as the answer if no one else has any ideas...

```
(.+)\s\(\w+\)\s\(|(.+)\s\(\d{3}\:\d{3}\s\-\s\d{3}\:\d{3}\)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following pattern will match everything, the result is stored into the `wanted` key :

```
$PATTERN = '/
    (?P<wanted>.*?)\s* # everything
    (\(.+\s.+\)\s+)? # maybe followed by
    (?= # that ends with
        \(\d{3}:\d{3}\s-\s\d{3}:\d{3}\)
    )
    /x';
preg_match($PATTERN, "Foo's (match11) this (100:200 - 300:400) the end", $matches);
var_dump($matches['wanted']);
preg_match($PATTERN, "Foo has (not matched) (100:200 - 300:400) the end", $matches);
var_dump($matches['wanted']);
preg_match($PATTERN, "Foo (100:200 - 300:400) the end", $matches);
var_dump($matches['wanted']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Tripple checked, in multiple Versions.

```
<?php

    $string[] = "Foo's (match11) this (100:200 - 300:400) ";
    $string[] = "Foo has (not_matched) (100:200 - 300:400) ";
    $string[] = "Foo (100:200 - 300:400) ";

    $reg = "~(.*)(\([^\)]*\))?\s\(\d{3}\:\d{3}\s\-\s\d{3}\:\d{3}\)~iU";

    foreach ( $string as $s ){
        preg_match_all ( $reg, $s, $m , PREG_SET_ORDER);

        print "<br />String: ". $s . "<br /><pre>";
        print_r ( $m );
        print "</pre><br />OR";
    print "The String Required is: " . $m[0][1] . "<br />";
    }

?>
```

Its working, and you can get the needed string on

```
$output = $m[0][1];
```